# excel calculate slope in range, ignoring leading zeros

Tags: excel, regression

I have this table:

```
     A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1    0  0  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Due to many lines of data, want to use the reference range $A1:$J1 and use LINEST() to calculate the slope on the above, but in a way so leading zero's won't be part of the calculation.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You've provided insufficient data and no expected results to use a [LINEST function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d).

Comment: What do you mean by "leading zeroes"? How is this different from saying just "zeroes"?

Comment: Nitek: So far I've been stuck at the very beginning by not being able to define a "dynamic" range. In the above table, I need a way for a reference range to dynamically shrink from A1:J1 to F1:J1 when the first non-zero observation appears in F1.
I have a function returning the relative position of the first non-zero observation, but I haven't been able to successfully couple it with another function to create this dynamic range.

Comment: Jeeped: No, LINEST returns the slope, in the case of F1:J1 it's 1. In case of A1:J1 it's 0.58.

Comment: XOR LX: That is zeroes before the first non-zero observation. If there are zeroes after the first non-zero observation they should be included in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=LINEST(OFFSET($A1,0,MATCH(TRUE,$A1:$J1<>0,0)-1,1,11-MATCH(TRUE,$A1:$J1<>0,0)))
```

The `OFFSET` function provides the dynamic range.

The `MATCH` function finds the first non-zero.

The formula is an array formula, so should be entered with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

This formula is volatile, which means it will recalculate whenever there is a change on your worksheet.  Depending on the size of your worksheet, this may or may not be a problem.

**EDIT**:  Since the original poster is having a problem, I have added a screen shot demonstrating that the formula as presented works on the data as posted:

[image]

Comment: The `MATCH(TRUE,$A1:$J1<>0,0)` returns #NA but I use `MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:J1<>0,0),0)` to get the position of the first non-zero value.

Comment: However, the OFFSET returns #VALUE if I use your suggested formula, incorporating the above MATCH-function.

Comment: @jeppe If you select the cell and examine the formula bar, do you see braces `{...}` around the formula?

Comment: @jeppe The MATCH function will also return #NA if you do not enter it properly as an array formula.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I've never used array functions before so I was unaware of the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and braces thing. It works, I really appreciate it!

Comment: As a note to future users, I should add that one has to exchange the "11" before the second MATCH with the number of columns in the range +1.